# Dynamically change a date in a URL, that is being called via API

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, url

Currently using React to build an App, using one of Nasa's API's. The API returns one Json value, for that specific day. I would ideally like to show the previous days, "picture of the day" on the app as well. The API url is

```
https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=DEMO_KEY&date=2020-07-23
```

Trying to figure out how I can dynamically change the date within the URL, to show the previous 4 days. I know a function would be best served here but can't wrap my head around how to potentially do it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

Using [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) and [Date.toISOString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString)

```js
const changeDate = (urlString, days) => {
  let url = new URL(urlString);
  let date = new Date(url.searchParams.get("date") + "T15:00:00.000Z"); // or new Date(); date.setHours(15,0,0,0) // normalise at 3pm
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);
  url.searchParams.set("date", date.toISOString().split("T")[0]);
  return url.href;
};

let newUrl = changeDate("https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=DEMO_KEY&date=2020-07-23", -4)

console.log(newUrl)
```

Comment: This is incredible and clearly, I have a long road ahead of me on this software journey. Really appreciate the help!